# How many Character Points for a Psionicist to buy proficiency with Restricted Weapons like Swords?

Tags: weapons, psionics, adnd-2e

In skills & powers for AD&D 2nd edition there's a rule that says

> "Character Class Restrictions Non-warrior characters are normally
> restricted by the rules dictating the types of weapons they can
> acquire proficiencies for. However, by spending extra character points
> for a weapon proficiency slot, a character can purchase a proficiency
> that he would otherwise not be able to possess. A rogue or a priest
> can acquire a proficiency for a weapon that is normally restricted to
> a warrior’s use. One additional character point must be spent when the
> slot is purchased—the slot will cost 4 points, instead of the 3 rogues
> and priests usually pay. A wizard can spend 2 additional character
> points to become proficient in a weapon normally allowed to a priest
> or a rogue. If the wizard wishes to become proficient with a weapon
> that is normally limited to fighters, however, he must spend 3 extra
> character points."

And a Table that lists penalties for non proficient and familiar:

> Warrior –2 –1
> Wizard –5 –3
> Priest –3 –2
> Rogue –3 –2
> Psionicist –4 –2
> Nonclassed NPC –4 –2

As a DM I am wondering what is a good Cost for Psionicists to use Class Restricted Weapons, as their penalties do not line up either with the Rogue/Priest (5 points total penalty) or the Wizard (8 points total penalty).

The cost theoretically appears to be 3 points if we think of them as Wizards, but they use d6/+2 for hit dice, and use Rogue THAC0, so should we use the 2 point penalty instead?

Additional notes: There are psionicist kits like Shinobi and Janissary that use restricted weapons.

Trivia: the 1st edition Psionicist in Dragon 78 was allowed "swords" but not Two-handed swords.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! it took a while but i found the answer in Skills & Powers in the Psionicist Section

the cost is 4 CP "Proficiency in a single weapon from the warrior list"